# python irc can't identify with irc server

Tags: python, irc

Where am I going wrong here. as far as i can tell this should work.

```
import socket, string

#some user data, change as per your taste
SERVER = 'irc.freenode.net'
PORT = 6667
NICKNAME = 'echoquote'
CHANNEL = '#python'
PASSWORD = 'nope'
import time
#open a socket to handle the connection
IRC = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#open a connection with the server
def irc_conn():
    IRC.connect((SERVER, PORT))

#simple function to send data through the socket
def send_data(command):
    IRC.send(command + '\n')

#join the channel
def join(channel):
    send_data("JOIN %s" % channel)

#send login data (customizable)
def login(nickname, username='user', password = None, realname='Pythonist', hostname='Helena', servername='Server'):
    send_data("USER %s %s %s %s" % (username, hostname, servername, realname))
    send_data("NICK " + nickname)
    send_data("nickserv identify %s %s\r\n" % (NICKNAME, PASSWORD))
    time.sleep(3)

irc_conn()
login(NICKNAME)
join(CHANNEL)

while (1):
    buffer = IRC.recv(1024)
    msg = string.split(buffer)
    message = ' '.join(msg[3:])
    message = ''.join([x for x in message if x in string.printable])
    if message:
        print message + '\n'
    if msg[0] == "PING": #check if server have sent ping command
        send_data("PONG %s" % msg[1]) #answer with pong as per RFC 1459
    if msg [1] == 'PRIVMSG' and msg[2] == NICKNAME:
        filetxt = open('/tmp/msg.txt', 'a+') #open an arbitrary file to store the messages
        nick_name = msg[0][:string.find(msg[0],"!")] #if a private message is sent to you catch it
        message = ' '.join(msg[3:])
        filetxt.write(string.lstrip(nick_name, ':') + ' -> ' + string.lstrip(message, ':') + '\n') #write to the file
        filetxt.flush() #don't wait for next message, write it now!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    send_data("nickserv identify %s %s\r\n" % (NICKNAME, PASSWORD))
```

There is no `nickserv` command in IRC. This is an alias in some IRC clients, and all it does is send a private message to NickServ. [Read the IRC specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459), and stop reinventing wheels — use an existing IRC library, eg. twisted.words, or an existing IRC bot solution.